# How can I update my sqlite database one row by row ? IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-update

I would like to update my database sqlite3 row by row like Android with an index for update a specific row. How I can use for do that ?

```
-(void) updateBddWithData:(Data*) data{ 

    sqlite3 *databaseOK=self.database;

    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &databaseOK) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString* updateIntoBdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ART_TABLE SET ida = '%@' ,title = '%@' ,chapo = '%@' ,link = '%@' ,linkimg = '%@' ,pubdate = '%@' ,creator = '%@' ,description = '%@'  ",data.ide,data.title,data.chapo,data.link,data.linkImg,data.pubDate,data.creator,data.description];

        sqlite3_stmt* statement = NULL;

        int returnValue = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseOK, [updateIntoBdd UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL));

        if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK){

            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){

             // What can I do ?

             }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(databaseOK);
    }
}
```

When I call my method Update(object) I would like to update just one index row with my parameter object.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Use some library for SQLITE , for example https://github.com/ogres/SQLiteDatabase-class-for-iOS-Objective-C

Comment: It's not possible without library ?

Comment: yes , it is possible , but you have to write at least time times more code for doing it without library,

you should first select rows , then forech row update it and you should deal with types/columns ...etc , with library , you can just select and write another query for update , all other ( sqlite ) stuff will be managed by the library

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reinventing the wheel I would suggest to use a wrapper like [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

However, if you really want to do it without a wrapper:

```
-(void) updateBddWithData:(Data*) data { 

    sqlite3 *databaseOK=self.database;

    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &databaseOK) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString* updateIntoBdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ART_TABLE (ida, title, chapo, link, linkimg, pubdate, creator, description) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", data.ide, data.title, data.chapo, data.link, data.linkImg, data.pubDate, data.creator, data.description];

        sqlite3_stmt* statement = NULL;

        const char *update_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseOK, insert_stmt,-1, &update_stmt, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
             //SUCCESS
        } 
        else {
            //ERROR
        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);

        sqlite3_close(databaseOK);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible without that ?

Comment: @Pierre_S It is possible. Check my edit. I really think you should try FMDatabase. It is a very easy to use and performant wrapper for sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `WHERE` clause in statement.

Normally, you have an `ID` (maybe this is your `ida`?) in table such that you may use:

```
UPDATE ART_TABLE SET ida = '%@', ... WHERE id ='%@';
```

Also consider using safer [sqlite3_bind_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: I have an id in my database but it's auto increment, my ida it's different to the database id. And I want to update just one row with an index up to my database end.

Comment: So, you must use `UPDATE ... WHERE id=#`, where `#` is `id` from row you want to update.